# Paging html table by columns on pdf printing

Tags: html, css, pdf, printing, media-queries

I have a HTML table with 50 ore more Columns, My requirement is if columns doesn't fit in 1 page they should move to next page when printing to PDF.

My html page looks fine with scroll bar to show all columns in one page in a chrome browser.
But when selecting **Print** pdf the columns are being cut  instead or being rendered in a new page.

below is my table html and the css solution I tried https://jsfiddle.net/L91twny2/

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media print
{
  table { page-break-after:auto }
  tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
  td    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
  thead { display:table-header-group }
  tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table">
  <thead style="color:#ceb03d">
    <tr>
      <th id="Column_Part1_1">Column_Part11</th>
      <th id="Column_Part1_2">Column_Part12</th>
      <th id="Column_Part1_3">Column_Part13</th>
      <th id="Column_Part1_4">Column_Part14</th>
      <th id="Column_Part1_5">Column_Part15</th>
      <th id="Column_Part1_6">Column_Part16</th>
      <th id="Column_Part1_7">Column_Part17</th>
      <th id="Column_Part1_8">Column_Part18</th>
      <th id="Column_Part1_9">Column_Part19</th>
      <th id="Column_Part1_10">Column_Part110</th>
      <th id="Column_Part1_11">Column_Part111</th>
      <th id="Column_Part1_12">Column_Part112</th>
      <th id="Column_Part1_13">Column_Part113</th>
      <th id="Column_Part1_14">Column_Part114</th>
      <th id="Column_Part1_15">Column_Part115</th>
      <th id="Column_Part1_15">Column_Part115</th>
      <th id="Column_Part2_1">Column_Part21</th>
      <th id="Column_Part2_2">Column_Part22</th>
      <th id="Column_Part2_3">Column_Part23</th>
      <th id="Column_Part2_4">Column_Part24</th>
      <th id="Column_Part2_5">Column_Part25</th>
      <th id="Column_Part2_6">Column_Part26</th>
      <th id="Column_Part2_7">Column_Part27</th>
      <th id="Column_Part2_8">Column_Part28</th>
      <th id="Column_Part2_9">Column_Part29</th>
      <th id="Column_Part2_10">Column_Part210</th>
      <th id="Column_Part2_11">Column_Part211</th>
      <th id="Column_Part2_12">Column_Part212</th>
      <th id="Column_Part2_13">Column_Part213</th>
      <th id="Column_Part2_14">Column_Part214</th>
      <th id="Column_Part2_15">Column_Part215</th>
      <th id="Column_Part2_15">Column_Part215</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in model.items"> //The table contains several Columns.
      <td>Value_Part_1</td>
      <td>Value_Part_12</td>
      <td>Value_Part_13</td>
      <td>Value_Part_14</td>
      <td>Value_Part_15</td>
      <td>Value_Part_16</td>
      <td>Value_Part_17</td>
      <td>Value_Part_18</td>
      <td>Value_Part_19</td>
      <td>Value_Part_110</td>
      <td>Value_Part_111</td>
      <td>Value_Part_112</td>
      <td>Value_Part_113</td>
      <td>Value_Part_114</td>
      <td>Value_Part_115</td>
      
      <td>Value_Part_21</td>
      <td>Value_Part_22</td>
      <td>Value_Part_23</td>
      <td>Value_Part_24</td>
      <td>Value_Part_25</td>
      <td>Value_Part_26</td>
      <td>Value_Part_27</td>
      <td>Value_Part_28</td>
      <td>Value_Part_29</td>
      <td>Value_Part_210</td>
      <td>Value_Part_211</td>
      <td>Value_Part_212</td>
      <td>Value_Part_213</td>
      <td>Value_Part_214</td>
      <td>Value_Part_215</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]